# RSA key usually requires password, but doesn't on original machine?

Tags: ssh, password

I created the RSA key and uploaded it to the remote machines I wanted to SSH to. However, I realized that, on my local machine, I can SSH straight in without entering my passphrase. On the remote machines, when I want to SSH to another, I have to enter my passphrase as expected.

I don't seem to be running ssh-agent or ssh-ident (or at least running 'service ssh-agent' returns unrecognized service). What could be allowing this to happen? I'd imagine that the passphrase must be stored somewhere, and if it's in plaintext I'd like to disable this function.

Comment: What about `pgrep -fl ssh-agent`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to return anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't the gnome keyring provide its own agent (`gnome-authentication-agent`)? it might be worth grepping for just `agent` and/or running `ssh-add -L` to see any cached identities

Comment: `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` -- you are most probably using `gnome-keyring`, which remembers your passphrase/decrypted key. The `ssh-agent` is not a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jakuje, yes it was the keyring. I likely added it to the keyring when creating the key, and it unlocks automatically upon login. Interestingly, the keyring has a "Security" measure or score that I'm not familiar with. I'm guessing it's related to the number of bits?